# How can you estimate distance of an object by its redshift?

Tags: distances, redshift, astrometry

Is there a way to take the red shift of an object and, from that, calculate a rough estimate of its distance from us (in parsecs, preferably)?

Comment: Look up Hubble's Law.

Comment: @Phiteros Oh, I see. $v = cz$ and $v = H_0 d$, so $d = \frac{cz}{H_0}$. I didn't scroll far enough down Wikipedia to see $v=cz$ :/

Comment: Keep in mind that that's just an approximation; you have to go through a lot more complicated differential equations for high redshifts.

Comment: @Phiteros Yes, that's fine. I don't need anything accurate

Comment: Just to clarify, at high redshifts it's not only inaccurate, it's completely wrong. For $z\lesssim 0.1$ it's fine, at $z=3$ you'll overestimate the distance by a factor of two, at $z=10$ by a factor of five, and at $z=1100$ by a factor of 350.

Comment: Use online calculator such as this: http://www.astro.ucla.edu/~wright/CosmoCalc.html

Comment: @Phiteros Out of curiosity, what is the differential equation that I'd have to solve?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble%27s_law#Derivation_of_the_Hubble_parameter